# How to remove user access to application if their JWT / cookie is still valid

Tags: node.js, http, cookies, jwt, express-jwt

So a user logs in successfully, and they get a valid JWT that we store as an encrypted cookie in their browser.

Later down the road, we want to revoke this user's access, and we flip a boolean on the user model in the database - `hasAccess: false` - but the problem is that their cookie is still good.

To do a significant optimization, our server just looks at the token/cookie, and if it's valid, forgoes a trip to the database to look for the user model.

The only way I can think to solve this, is to store a hash of "blacklisted" usernames in memory on the server.

Does anyone know of a good way to solve this? Seen a similar problem?

Comment: have you tried: `JWTAuth::invalidate($token);` ?

Comment: I am using `require('jwt-simple')`...but the original problem is that I don't know when to invalidate the token. The database right now is the only thing that can tell me to invalidate the token, but I am try to save a trip to the database.

Comment: The only way I can think to solve it is to update the server when there is a change to the database to tell the server that user access has changed. The server will have to cache a list of invalid users, and then invalidate the token upon the next request with that token.

Comment: This solution is not scalable. If the number of invalid users is very high, then you will have to have a huge memory dedicated to storing the invalid user list at all times. It's better to make a trip to the database and invalidate the user.

Comment: You can keep a short expiration time. If your logic is to invalidate the user anyways why not expire it and give fresh tokens upon return.

Comment: @mrtyormaa I agree - in this case, we only have a few hundred users, so it will be ok, but I agree that in general my solution will not scale (using server memory to store invalidated users)